# repl.it how do you upload a directory

Tags: file, replit

Is there a way to quickly upload all a directory and all of its files to the repl.it IDE? If not it would be very useful for migrating large projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nope!

You can of course upload individual files and make folders, but that's honestly too much work. If I were you, I'd switch to a better editor, like PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

uploading directories is currently a feature being developed but we do not provide that at the moment